# What command can fix visual output (layout)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can someone tell me why the columns are arranged like that or tell how to fix it ?

Thanks

[image: visual error]

```
# import libraries 

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from time import time
import mysql.connector
from IPython.display import display # Allows the use display() for dataframes

data = pd.read_csv("car_dataset.csv", delimiter = ";")

# Display result (example (5))
display(data.head(n=5))
```

I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, your data is delimited by `,` not `;`. Remove the `delimiter` parameter.

```
data = pd.read_csv("car_dataset.csv")
```